# Understanding WordPress' post type support

Tags: metabox, post-type-support

I was hoping if someone could help me better understand WordPress' post type support.

```
remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'author' );
```

Above in example doesn't seem to actually remove the support, just hide things like (post) meta boxes and (edit) columns more globally compared to this example:

```
remove_meta_box( 'authordiv', 'post', 'normal' );
// unset( $columns['author'] );
```

Guessing because of this some modifications will be made to `add_post_type_support` sooner or later.

For future compatibility, which out of the above would you suggest for simply hiding things? (removing the `author` post type support could really mess up your site if `remove_post_type_support` would *actually* drop the support)

Answer (score 1):

When you register post type, you can choose what support you need. For Example:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books', 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ) );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' )
```

In this way you will create post type **Books** only with **Title Option and Editor**

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but this doesn't exactly answers my question, mainly about `remove_post_type_support` 's exact functionality.